# Is there a word for people who are addicted to jewelry?

Tags: single-word-requests

A gold-lover specifically is referred to as a [***crysophilist***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chrysophilist). Is there a word for jewelry lovers in general (diamonds, pearls, rubies, platinum ;not restricted to gold alone) to the point where the "love" has turned into an addiction?

**Usage Example:**

> My aunt is a real ________.   She would even go without food for days but not without adorning herself with precious metals and rare gems.

I reckon if such a word exists, it would possibly end with a *phile*. Any suggestions (either a noun or an adjective)?

Comment: Not an actual word, but as people who study gems are called gemologists, you could argue via similar "love of" constructions that you could call your aunt a **gemophile**.

Comment: Jewel addict....

Answer (score 2):

***1. gemmaphile*** (polite) or 2. ***Jewel-junkie*** (impolite)

**gem** derives from the Latin **gemma** according to [Etymoline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?l=g&p=7&allowed_in_frame=0)

> a precious stone" (especially when cut or polished), c. 1300, probably
>   from Old French gemme (12c.), from Latin gemma "precious stone,
>   jewel,"

**phile** as we all know derives from the Greek philos, loving (See [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/-phile))

But this combines a Latin root with a Greek root, which I once read is not quite proper.  However, [Wikipedia on Hybrid Word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_word) gives many examples, e.g., automobile and bigamy.

2. The impolite word, **jewel-junkie**

Jewel does not need to be defined.  **Junkie**, as defined by [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/junkie?jss=0)

> a person with an insatiable craving for something:  a chocolate junkie

from [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/junkie)

> a person who gets an unusual amount of pleasure from or has an unusual
>   amount of interest in something: television news junkie

The first definition of junkie is "drug addict", but the second definition in these and several other references is to a legal, even innocent, craving.

Jewel-junkie would be OK in the US, if said in an affectionate way, but might be over the line somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

*My aunt is a real **jewel freak**. She would even go without food for days but not without adorning herself with precious metals and rare gems.*

> [FREAK](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22jewel+fiend%22&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_xMuMsdXLAhWBVhoKHQxIAgcQ_AUIBygA&biw=417&bih=275&dpr=2#q=%22a+jewel+freak%22)
>
> a :  an ardent enthusiast *film freaks*
>
> b :  a person who is obsessed with something *a control freak*
>
> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/freak)

Also, ***jewel fiend***

> [FIEND](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22a+jewel+fiend%22&biw=448&bih=294&noj=1&prmd=ivsn&ei=ltPxVoinKsjxar2MptAL&start=0&sa=N&dpr=2)
>
> a : a person extremely devoted to a pursuit or study :  fanatic *a golf fiend*
>
> b : an addict *a dope fiend*
>
> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fiend)

Answer (score 1):

Years ago, when the ladies wished to comment on a gauche woman's inappropriate attempt to wear every piece of jewelry she owned, the phrase, "Oh, look, it's ***The Queen of Sheba***," would often be heard. Apparently "The Urban Dictionary" has usurped the usage of this phrase (as I was familiar with it in my childhood) to something more akin to "uppity".

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Queen%20of%20Sheba

In keeping with the recognized authority of TUD, the correct term is: ***bling ho***.

Answer (score 1):

**blingoholic**

Per Wiktionary, *bling* (originally *[bling-bling](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bling_bling#English)*) is a slang term for jewelry, especially shiny jewelry that represents an ostentatious display of wealth. And the suffix *[-holic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-holic)* is a [back-formation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-formation), with the ending of "alcoholic" (denoting alcohol addiction, or a person so addicted) reinterpreted as a general suffix indicative of addiction, and used in such terms as *[chocoholic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chocoholic)* or *workaholic*.

This is not found in dictionaries, but neither are the suggestions from some other responses ("gemmaphile") and the wording of your questions seems to be asking for coined terms and not necessarily actual words.

Comment: What it should be is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Hi ghostarbeiter, your answer was flagged as low-quality. I'd normally say "possibly because it's too short or not detailed enough" but I think it's obvious why this one got flagged. :P Amusing as it is, @NVZ rightly points out that it should have been a comment, and you have enough rep to post them. I'm recommending this answer for deletion on that basis. - [From Review](http://english.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/171461)

Comment: The current top rated answer invents the terms "gemmaphile", which is entirely unknown to Google, and "jewel-junkie". Both of these were simply coined by the poster. On the other hand, the original poster appears to be asking for suggestions and not necessarily actual words.

Comment: From the gemmaphile and jewel-junkie answerer:  If you examine my answer, you will find logic and citations for the component parts of the words I coined.  Yes, you are right, I coined them.  If you had done the same for blingoholic, I don't think it would have been flagged.  I will cheerfully give you a +1 for blingoholic if you expand your answer using my answer or Elian's answer or the many other answers with logic and citations as a model.

Comment: +1 for the edited answer. (I hope your answer gets out of the hole it is in.)

Comment: +1 for correcting your answer, even though I was first to answer "bling":)

Answer (score -1):

Consider these

[**Ornate**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ornate)

> Elaborately, heavily, and often excessively ornamented.

[**Bling**](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bling)

> Denoting expensive, ostentatious clothing or jewellery, or the style or materialistic attitudes associated with them

Comment: This doesn't answer the question ("a word for people who are addicted to jewelry").

Comment: @ghostarbeiter I have to agree. It's hard to find an exact word.