# Word for person attracted to shiny things

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, russian

In Russian we have the word *сор**о**ка* (magpie) for a person that (among other negative traits) likes and is attracted to shiny things (e.g. gold), usually cheap ones like fake jewelry, or just kind of hoards cheap things in general.

**What is the closest equivalent to this in English (preferably American English), if there is one of course?**

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/315141/is-there-a-word-for-people-who-are-addicted-to-jewelry

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/544064/365490

Comment: @user121863 related, but definitely not the same.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul related, not the same.

Comment: racoon, i do believe

Comment: *ooh shiny* : A person being distracted or silly, as if their mind is on something else. Like a bird looking at a shiny stone. – [UD](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ooh%20shiny)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Perhaps surprisingly, the answer is in your own question: "сорока" = *magpie*

> magpie (countable noun): If you describe someone as a magpie, you mean that they like collecting and keeping things, often things that have little value.
>
> {informal} "A born magpie, Mandy collects any object that catches her eye."
>
> [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/magpie)

For example:

> "Magpies do not steal trinkets and are positively scared of shiny objects, according to new research.
>
> The study appears to refute the myth of the “thieving magpie”, which pervades European folklore.
>
> It is widely believed that magpies have a compulsive urge to steal sparkly things for their nests."
>
> [BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science-environment-28797519)

Comment: This definition of [magpie](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/magpie) can be found in American dictionaries, and some Americans will recognize it, even though they [don't live](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-billed_magpie) in [most of the U.S.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow-billed_magpie)

Comment: According to Google Ngrams, the phrase "like a magpie" is used twice as often in British books as it is in American. I would agree that *magpie* is the equivalent that you are looking for, but not everyone will understand what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

@Anton's answer of *magpie* is probably the way to go here. But I feel compelled to throw in

> *positive phototaxis* which is the compulsion of an organism to move towards bight objects. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phototaxis)) Like a moth to a flame.

Next time I'm feeling clever with my wife, I'll be sure to use this one.

Answer (score 0):

Bling often implies a certain degree of cheapness in the quality of the shiny jewelry, or hubcaps, or whatever else, so a person who likes a lot of bling.  Maybe a "Bling Diva" or "Bling Master" or some such combination of words would work.

Comment: A tempting opportunity to invent. J_Hat is on it with "bling", but that is a thing not a person, and though softly negative, not overly so. So... Blingaddict? Blingslut? Blinger?

Answer (score 0):

This uses a liberal amount of figurative language and pop culture, but I have heard several people use the term "[niffler](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Niffler)" to refer to someone that loves shiny things. This is a reference to the magical animal in the Harry Potter franchise that are attracted to shiny things. This would definitely be non-standard, since it is a figurative reference to something in popular culture, so this would only be useful in very informal settings with people familiar with that series.

Answer (score -1):

*Ostentatious* comes to mind. And *tacky* has more negativity.

Comment: You should include linked dictionary definitions for your suggested words.